# JSONObject ClassNotFoundException in Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, json

I want to create an `JSONObject` in my `Servlet`:

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
[...]    
Map<String, String> data1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
Map<String, String> data2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
data1.put("name", "f1");
data1.put("key", "aa1");
data1.put("value", "21");
data2.put("name", "f2");
data2.put("key", "aa2");
data2.put("value", "22");

JSONObject json1 = new JSONObject(data1);
```

But when I run my application, I get the exception:

```
exception 
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception    

root cause 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONObject
    servlet.LoginServlet.doPost(LoginServlet.java:71)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:643)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)


root cause 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONObject
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    servlet.LoginServlet.doPost(LoginServlet.java:71)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:643)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
```

I have used the following json resource:
https://code.google.com/p/org-json-java/downloads/list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Download java-json jar file and add it into class path.
>
> For Classpath reference: Right click on project in eclipse ->
>   Buildpath -> Configure Build path -> Java Build Path (left Pane) ->
>   Libraries(Tab) -> Add External Jars -> Select your jar and select ok.

Comment: So the one I got from https://code.google.com/p/org-json-java/downloads/list is not the right one?

Comment: Did you add this in classpath?

Comment: Yes I had added in Java Build Path --> Libraries --> Add External Jars, but still no same problem

Comment: Can you try with this jar file http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavajsonjar.htm?

Comment: Yeah that one I just tried, but still ClassNotFoundException... :/

Comment: Remove old jar from classpath and add this new jar into class path entry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96553/discussion-between-user3236180-and-shiladittya-chakraborty).

Comment: The solution was to add the jar also to:WebContent\WEB-INF\lib folder